# javascript: All device data is read into the object

Tags: javascript

When I write Javascript, I want to read all the data of the device into the object, but only the last one is read.
I would like to ask how I can read all the data in the device into obj, thank you.

```js
let data = [
      {
          "bind": "82218018295591013",
          "account": "admin",
          "password": "0000",
          "devices": [
              {
                  "ip": "192.168.0.88",
                  "brand_name": "UNIVIEW",
                  "name": "UNIVIEW"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "bind": "94907378021478863",
          "account": "admin",
          "password": "0000",
          "devices": [
              {
                  "ip": "192.168.0.88",
                  "brand_name": "UNIVIEW",
                  "name": "UNIVIEW"
              },
              {
                  "ip": "192.168.0.89",
                  "brand_name": "hisharp",
                  "name": "hisharp"
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
  
  let obj = {};
  
  function getObj() {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < data[i].devices.length; j++) {
              obj.devices = data[i].devices[j];
          }
      }

      return obj;
  }

  console.log('obj :>> ', obj);
  getObj();
```

Comment: This is what your loop does, effectively: `obj.devices = data[0].devices[0]; obj.devices = data[1].devices[0]; obj.devices = data[1].devices[1];`. You assign `obj.devices` to some value, then you assign it to some different value. Why do you believe that the first value will be kept? What is the expected result? Aren’t you looking for an array like `const devices = [];`, then in the loop do `devices.push(data[i].devices[j]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a single object for all objects and you store all objects, but the problem is that each time that you store an object, you are overriding the previous one with it.

```
  function getObj(obj) {
      obj.devices = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          obj.devices.concat(data[i].devices);
      }

      return obj;
  }
```

and pass `obj`:

```
  getObj(obj);
  console.log('obj :>> ', obj);
```